# Отдельные поля в метод Create Laravel

Tags: laravel

Как в Laravel в метод `Post::create($request->all())` добавить еще поля? input hidden не подойдет, так как данные приватные, которые нельзя изменять.
Пытался вот так, не получается:

```
Post::create($request->all(), ['user', Auth::user()->id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
Post::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['user', Auth::user()->id]));
```